# How do I get SQL Server Management Studio to find a .bak file to restore?

Tags: backup, database, sql-server, sql

I am trying to turn a .bak file into a database. I can't find the "Restore Database" button when I left-click "databases" when connected. [This is what I *should* see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7P0a.png). However, [this is what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2m9U.png)

I have been using [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/50354/restoring-a-sql-database-backup-using-sql-server-management-studio/) tutorial to try to restore a database from a .bak file. I placed the .bak file (named *WideWorldImporters-Standard*) in the *SQL Server Management Studio* folder. [Here's the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt4MC.png)

Things I've tried:

- Restarting the Server Management Studio
- Restarting my computer
- Looking for updates on Server Management Studio
- Looking for updates on my computer
- Copying the .bak file to other folders and trying to open it as a
  file
- Looking for anything weird going on with azure

I suspect that the problem might be that I am not connecting to the right database. The program seems to be logging into my azure account just fine, but I am not [finding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCaES.png) any of my existing servers to hook into.

Comment: Backup/Restore commands are not available in SSMS in Azure SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore the database using the backup file using T-SQL:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY   
    FROM DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorks2017.bak' ;  
    GO  

--Restore database from backup


RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorks2017]
            FROM DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorks2017.bak'
            WITH  FILE = 1,  
                  MOVE N'AdventureWorks2017'           TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2017.mdf',  
                  MOVE N'AdventureWorks2017_log'       TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\AdventureWorks2017_log.ldf',  
                  NOUNLOAD,
                  REPLACE,
                STATS = 20
            GO
```

Change the folder path and filenames as per your environment. If you get an error of "Permission denied" while executing the code move the .bak file to the default backup directory for the instance.
The `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` is to check the logical names for the database files.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way around my problem. Apparently, my `.bak` file was corrupt. I got it from multiple places and still got the same problem. (Don't know how or why)

I then downloaded the `.bacpac` file for the same database, and then used SQLBackupAndFTP to put the file onto my Azure server as a database. I can now access it with Microsoft SQL Management Studio and LINQPad 5. I can play around with SQL commands on the Db just fine now. I don't know if Visual Studio can access it, but I am optimistic.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the issue you posted on your question has something to do with the workaround you figured out.